# Using same custom array adapter for listview and grid view

Tags: android, performance, android-widget

I have a dashboard showing files in two type of views Grid View and List View.
I am using two seperate custom array adapter object for both. Is there any way to use same array adapter for both the views

```
ArrayList<DocumentItem> documentsList = new ArrayList<DocumentItem>();
```

Currently the grid view adapter looks like

```
DocumentsListAdapter gridAdapter = new DocumentsListAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_documentitem, documentsList);
```

and list view looks like

```
DocumentsListAdapter listAdapter = new DocumentsListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_documentitem, documentsList);
```

Both differs by layout using to display items. Please guide me to overcome this duplication

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to use genric class and use separate object for both listview and gridview to access it.

Comment: Are you saying what am doing is correct? But when i added a new item to one view, i have to duplicate the code to reflect it in other one. Is there any way to do this.